# Why would autocommit in django 1.4 slow down unit tests?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, unit-testing

Django 1.4 operates by default with the database-level autocommit setting off. I have recently tried turning this setting on and it has slowed down my test suite considerably.

`DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'].update({'autocommit': True})`

My understanding is that now every call to `create`, `save` etc. by default opens a transaction and issues a commit statement. Would the cost of all these additional transactions be enough to explain the slow-down of the unit tests? How does the django `TestCase` transaction behaviour come in to play with this (operating each test within a transaction and rolling back once completed)? Should we expect the performance reduction in the unit tests to be reflective of performance of the views in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowed down unit tests were due to the additional cost of opening and committing a transaction with every object created as part of `setUp`, and did not reflect a slow down in performance in a live environment.